# EAV modelled database schema to store settings, is this the correct way?

Tags: database, database-design

[image]

I'm designing a database schema to store app and user settings for this I have chosen to use the EAV model. Have I done it the right way?

Comment: See [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid (point #3)](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) for a discussion of why EAV is really really bad, and see [Bad CaRMa](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=292) for a true horror story of an EAV system design that ruined a thriving company.

Comment: @marc_s  I have already read that article while researching on the topic, and after comparing all the benefits and limitations I have decided to go with it.

Comment: Nowadays I would choose to store "app and user settings" in a JSON column on the "app" or "user" table. All modern DBMS offer good support for querying JSON values (and Postgres can index them very efficiently)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Will it be ok If I store user settings in a JSON column while storing with app wide configuration in the EAV model schema like I have posted above?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name while using JSON column how do you make sure that the settings name ( json keys ) are named consistently every where?

Comment: You could use json schema validator for that